# How to push an object in to an array and store in the localstorage

Tags: javascript

This is my Object

```
var studentObject = {
        "REG_NO": regNo,
        "NAME": name,
        "SSC": ssc,
        "HSC": hsc,
        "GRADUATION": graduate
 };
```

This is my empty array

```
var tableDisplay = [];
```

push the studentObject into tableDisplay array and store it in localStorage it should in this format

```
[
{
"REG_NO": regNo,
"NAME": name,
"SSC": ssc,
"HSC": hsc,
"GRADUATION": graduate
}
]
```

Comment: What did you try and how it's not working?

Answer (score 4):

To push the object into the array:

```
tableDisplay.push(studentObject);
```

To store it in the localStorage you have to stringify it:

```
localStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify(tableDisplay));
```

Then parse it when retrieving it:

```
tableDisplay = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableDisplay"));
```